# Render template string to string .net core (without a view file)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I need render a template string on .net core. (without a view file)

In .net Framework RazorEngine.Templating make this for me, like this code exemple

```
public static string Parse<T>(string template, T model, Dictionary<string, object> viewBagParameters = null)
    {
        var viewBag = new DynamicViewBag();
        if (viewBagParameters != null && viewBagParameters.Any())
            viewBag.AddDictionaryValues(viewBagParameters);
        return RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(template, model, viewBag, template.GetHashCode().ToString());
    }
```

RazorEngine don't exist in .net core (yet)